# Deploy Angular on Tomcat with redirect configuration

Tags: angular, tomcat, deployment

I want to deploy my Angular 5 app on a Tomcat 7 server, but there is a problem on redirection when i click on refresh button, i got always 404 error.
On the angular site web, i found for Apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

It works for Apache server but not for Tomcat, is there a similar config for Tomcat?
Thank you

Comment: i use angular for the web site.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55612266/1298824) may help

Answer (score 0):

One solution to avoid the redirect it to fall back to using the hash mode:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})
```

Another option would be to write a dedicated Java servlet that would do the redirect.