# 404 ERROR when an angular application deployed on tomcat server is reloaded

Tags: angular

I deployed an angular application on tomcat server, application is in webapp/test/dist folder. when i run tomcat http://localhost:8080/test/dist/ the page will open at this point if i click on a link it will open an other page. at this point if refresh the page or copy and paste the url in new tab leads to 404 error. I need to configure the tomcat server so that it should return index.html which is in webapp/test/dist/ folder when requested file not found instead of returning 404. i added  in server.xml and I created rewrite.config file in conf/catalina/localhost/rewrite.config but i dont know what i have to write please help me.

Comment: you need a rewrite url for your tomcat server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299430/deploy-angular-application-on-apache-tomcat-404-deep-links-issue

Comment: When ever you are deploying the angular application to tomcat, you need build the project with —base–href option,Please follow the below url for reference.
https://sudhasoftjava.wordpress.com/2018/05/17/angular-deployment-in-tomcat-with-aot-option/

Comment: @sudhakar even though i didnt use --base--href to set path, i set path manually in the generated index.html.

Comment: @Riscie I wrote the rewrite config its content is :                                
 RewriteCond       %{REQUEST_URI}        ^/*                                                    //we are matching all condition pattern
RewriteRule         ^/test/dist/*$              ^/test/dist/index.html [L]

Comment: after using querySelector method it  started working but here URL is getting changed. is there no any other way other than these query selector method and HashLocationStrategy method ?

Answer (score 0):

In your app.module.ts import:

```
import {HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
```

In the providers section add:

```
{provide: LocationStrategy,
  useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
```

and Test.