# How to configure fallback url in apache tomcat 9

Tags: angular, angular-routing, fallback, tomcat9

I am trying to deply angular 8 app with routing in apache tomcat 9.

I have use `ng build --prod --base-href=/ng-app/` to build distributables.

I am placing ng-app folder in webapps folder of tomcats. It renders `localhost:8080/ng-app` properly but whenever I try to access `localhost:8080/ng-app/users` it's giving me 404.

I understand from [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) that I need to configure fallback for angular in the app server, so that it redirects to index.html if any thing under `ng-app/` is not found.

I came across configuration for apache http server, ngnix, etc. But I couldn't find same for apache tomcat 9.

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299430/deploy-angular-application-on-apache-tomcat-404-deep-links-issue) helps you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution

First I had to add (not replace) below line under HOST

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
```

I think the above configuration is for tomcat to read rewrite config which I am about to mention below -

and create file `rewrite.config` in `/conf/Catalina/localhost/` directory and add below rule -

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} !-f
RewriteRule ^/ng-app/(.*) /ng-app/index.html
```

This rule basically redirects to /ng-app/index.html if anything below /ng-app/ is not found.
Now it's working as expected.